# TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute' __getitem__' when run scrapy spider

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I have got this error when running scrapy project 
my spider.py code is

```
import scrapy
import re
from tutorial.items import TutorialItem

class tutorialSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name="tutorial"
    allowed_domain=['examble.com']
    start_urls = ["examble.com/something"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="post-entry"]/div/article'):
            item = TutorialItem()
            item['Title'] = sel.xpath('div[2]/h2/a/text()').extract[0]
            item['MainPageUrl'] = sel.xpath('div[2]/h2/a/@href').extract[0]
            item['Author'] = sel.xpath('div[2]/div/span/a/text()').extract[0]
            request = scrapy.Request(item['MianPageUrl'], callback=self.parseContentDetails)            
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parseContentDetails(self,response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['Content'] = response.xpath()
        item['Count'] = response.xpath()
        print type(item)
        return item
```

and my pipeline.py is

```
class TutorialPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #self.setupDBCon()
        #self.createTables()
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        for key, value in item.iteritems():
            if(isinstance(value, list)):
                if value:
                    templist = []
                    for obj in value:
                        temp = self.stripHTML(obj)
                        templist.append(temp)
                    item[key] = templist
                else:
                    item[key] = ""
            else:
                item[key] = self.stripHTML(value)

        print item.get('Title', '')     
        return item
```

and my items.py is

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class TutorialItem(Item):
    Title=Field()
    Author = Field()
    MianPageUrl = Field()
    Content=Field()
    Count=Field()
```

please tell me the solution for this error. I have searched so many sites. that sites only tell instancemethod object has no attribute error in django but i want the solution for scrapy

Comment: Please post your traceback, the lines before (and including the `TypeError` line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling extract properly, for each extract you have to actual call the method then index it:

```
item['Title'] = sel.xpath('div[2]/h2/a/text()').extract()[0]
                                                       ^^^
```

If you just want the first element you can just use *extract_first*.

```
 item['Title'] = sel.xpath('div[2]/h2/a/text()').extract_first()
```